# Having problems with positioning the dropdown menu to the center

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm new to HTML/CSS and still learning, however right now i'm stuck.

I've tried to use the `right` tag in `.womenswear ul` to make the drop down menu move to the center but when i try to use `right` tag to position the drop down menu nothing happens.

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

You can see that the dropdown menu is moving out on the rightside.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here is the code:

HTML code:

```
<nav class="navigation">
<ul>
<li class="menswear"><a href="#">MEN'S WEAR</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">TOPWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">BOTTOMWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Colour Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>   
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">FOOTWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Boots</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sandals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Snickers</a></li>         
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Caps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scarves</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sunglasses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jewelry</a></li>              
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">SALE</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="womenswear"><a href="#">WOMEN'S WEAR</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown2"><a href="#">TOPWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown2"><a href="#">BOTTOMWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Colour Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>   
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown2"><a href="#">FOOTWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Boots</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sandals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Snickers</a></li>         
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown2"><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Caps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scarves</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sunglasses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jewelry</a></li>              
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown2"><a href="#">SALE</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code:

```
    .navigation {
        top: 20px;
      position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 1024px;
        height: 42px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    }

    .navigation a {
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
          -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
           -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
            -o-transition: all .25s ease;
               transition: all .25s ease;
    }


    /* MEN'S WEAR BUTTON */

    .menswear { 
      width:130px !important;
      height: 42px;
      float:left;
      list-style: none;
      background: #ddd;
      position: relative;
     }

     .menswear ul {
      overflow:hidden;
      background:black;
      opacity: 0.5px;
      width:1024px;
      height:300px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: relative;
      top:26px;
      visibility: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
         -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
          -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
           -o-transition: all .25s ease;
              transition: all .25s ease;  
    }

    .menswear:hover ul { visibility: visible; opacity: 0.9; }



    .menswear a {

      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      top: 12px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 9px 15px 11px 14px;
      color: #000;

    }

    .menswear a:hover {
        background: #000;
        color: #000;
    }

    .menswear a:hover:nth-child(1) { color: #fff; }



    .menswear li { background: transparent; }



    .dropdown1:nth-child(1) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      right: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 96px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown1:nth-child(2) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }

    .dropdown1:nth-child(3) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown1:nth-child(4) {

      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 63px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown1:nth-child(5) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      left: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 100px;
      padding-left: 42px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-top: 1px;

    }

    .dropdown1 a {
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
      left: 0px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #888;
    }

    .dropdown1 a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #fff; }

    .dropdown1 a:nth-child(1) { color: #cbcbcb; }

    .dropdown1 ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline;
      position: relative;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .dropdown1 ul li {
      position: relative;
      padding: 8px;
    bottom: 20px;
      right: 5px;
      font-size: 13.5px;
    }

    .dropdown1 ul li a { font-weight: normal; }

    /* WOMENS WEAR BUTTON */

    .womenswear { 
       width:158px !important;
       height: 42px;
       right: 2px;
       float:left;
       list-style: none;
       position: relative;
     }

     .womenswear ul {
      overflow:hidden;
      background: #000;
      opacity: 0.5px;

      width:1024px;
      height:300px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: relative;
      top:26px;
      visibility: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
         -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
          -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
           -o-transition: all .25s ease;
              transition: all .25s ease;  
    }

    .womenswear:hover { background: #000; }

    .womenswear a {

      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      top: 12px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #000;
      padding-top: 9px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 11px;
      padding-left: 14px;

    }

    .womenswear a:hover { color: #fff; }
    .womenswear:hover ul { visibility: visible; opacity: 0.9; }
    .womenswear li{ background: transparent; }

    .dropdown2:nth-child(1) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 96px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown2:nth-child(2) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }

    .dropdown2:nth-child(3) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown2:nth-child(4) {

      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 63px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown2:nth-child(5) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      left: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 100px;
      padding-left: 42px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-top: 1px;

    }

    .dropdown2 a {
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
      left: 0px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .dropdown2 a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #fff; }
    .dropdown2 a:nth-child(1) { color: #cbcbcb; }

    .dropdown2 ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline;
      position: relative;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .dropdown2 ul li {
      position: relative;
      padding: 8px;
    bottom: 20px;
      right: 5px;
      font-size: 13.5px;
    }

    .dropdown2 ul li a { font-weight: normal; }
```

Comment: small tip: `.womenswear ul` will apply to all `ul` elements inside that class, you should be more specific if you want to align those elements like that, give those lists a class name

Answer (score 0):

To center a HTML element via CSS rules you have two options:

`margin: 0 auto 0 auto;` on the element itself.

Or:

`text-align: center;` on a parent-element.

If your element is then still not centered:

Check: `margin`, `padding`, `text-indent`, `position`, `top` and ***`left:-20px;`***.

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript, to set the positions computationally.